# How do you force a larger viewport?

Tags: html, firefox, viewport

Normally, I would do it by embedding the website/webpage into an `<iframe>` and set a custom `width` and `height`. But for my purposes, the required page is secured against embedding into internal frame, as it should be.

But I would still like to be able to artificially expand my viewport without actually physically making the window larger than my screen - perhaps some way where the viewport just becomes larger and I can navigate using scrollbars. That's how it ought to work if the viewport is forced to be larger than the window - I think.

So, how would I go about doing this client-side? Currently, I use Firefox, so maybe there's some way to expand the viewport using Developer Tools or the Console, and such.

**EDIT #1**
I may have found a way. You can use the "Responsive Design View" part of the Developer Tools, and adding custom dimensions to get a larger viewport. This makes sense and it seems to work. But maybe there is a drawback or problem with doing this. Is this an okay method of artificially increasing viewport?

**EDIT #2**
The "Responsive Design View" tool on Firefox is capped at 10000x10000 viewport size. For what I want to do, I need to at least hit 20000x20000! So, I guess this doesn't work.

Comment: What screen are you displaying your website on if 10k x 10k isn't enough for you??

Comment: The type of screen has nothing to do with this... That's the whole point.

Comment: Responsive view in Dev tools is used to simulate viewing a page on a different-sized screens. I guess it does matter, because obviously the size is important to you, so I'm really curious in which scenario you need at least 20k x 20k size.

Comment: That is true. The reason I need that resolution because the page I am expanding is a online game map page (think like Google Maps), where the viewport size determines how much of the "map" loads. So, I need to test a 20000x20000 viewport, and make it load at once.

The why of it doesn't really affect my question - nor does it allow for a way around making the viewport bigger. The goal is simple: How do I make a 20000x20000 viewport on Firefox/Chrome inside a normal sized window?